# Need to get arrow key codes from stdin after reading file using stdin

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, nasm

I am creating a NASM assembly code to read 2d array of numbers present in file from stdin
i am running the executable like this -> **./abc < input.txt** .

and after that i will display the read 2d array on terminal then i want to get keys codes   of **arrow keys** (which normal appear in terminal as special characters) i wrote code for it but its not working. ( I did echo off in termios setting for that)

Although it was working when i am taking file name as an argument & reading and not from stdin but using fopen with proper fd.

**./abc abc.txt**

in this case after displaying the read 2d array i am able to get arrow keys codes in program but not in earlier case.

Please help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using input redirection you disconnect stdin from your terminal and instead connect it to a pipe that your shell is reading the file into.

You could use `cat input.txt - | ./abc`, but you would have to pres <kbd>Enter</kbd> to flush the line buffer and make `cat` pipe the current line into your program.

I would suggest not messing with stdin and just taking the input file as an argument, like you already did before.